# Spiritual work of past life

Tags: scripture, vedas, shiva, krishna, yoga

Suppose I get initiated into a mantra and chanted it in my past life would I need initiation to chant that same mantra in this life

Comment: Yes there is something like that .. searching for one of my answers regarding the same topic but not getting it.

Comment: In a parallel context , (chapter 6 of Bhagavad Gita ) Arjuna poses a similar question (6.37,38,39), about a person who is endowed with faith in dhyana, yet has an unrestrained  mind , insufficient to subdue passions etc. ensuing the incapability of attaining the perfection due to inadequacy , what happens to such a person who has fallen off from both the paths(path of karma , path dhyana)?Lord Krishna the only One who can dispel such doubts answers. (There is no fall for one who pursues dhyana with pure(shraddha) intentions , Na hi kalyana krith kashchid , durgathim thaatha gacchathi)

Comment: (Subsequent verses say)He would be born in a conducive family (next birth) and pursue from where he left off in previous life . Sincere efforts do not go for a toss .But Shankara Bhashya says , if the person in trapped in some other karma in the next life , despite being born in  conducive family , there could be some delay in pursual. Whether it is the same mantra etc. is untold

Comment: Finally found it --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23416/4732 .. Deities particularly Surya are the witness of our spiritual Karma done in the past life. Surya is thus requested to help us take the correct mantra in the current life.